# Can I ask a question about real-world tasks for a statistician?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Thanks in advance!

Is it ok to ask about some examples of real-world tasks for a statistician?

Is "MATHEMATICS" the right place to ask or I should try the "Workplace" community.

I'm not asking the actual question here (on meta), but if someone answers, it would be also great to know possible time given to do a task. Also it would be great to know how loaded a statistician could be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest looking at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) site instead. But as it's currently worded, your questions would probably be seen as too broad, so I do not recommend jumping to Ask Question page. Begin by considering the following questions, which already have answers  addressing some aspects of your question.

- [What are some examples of “real world” problems that can be modeled using vector autoregressive models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12984)
- [Documented/reproducible examples of successful real-world applications of econometric methods?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6976)
- [Real-life examples of Markov Decision Processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/145122)
- [Applying machine learning in a real world example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/174135)